# List comprehension and len() vs. simple for loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm supposed to take a list of words and count all words in it which are 2 or more characters long and where the first and last character are equal.

I came up with two possible solutions:

```
result = 0
for word in words:
    if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]:
        result += 1
return result
```

vs.

```
return len([word for word in words if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]])
```

Which one would be the preferred solution? Or are there even better ones?

Comment: I would take #2: but formatted nicely on multiple lines. Just because you *can* write it one line doesn't mean you should (even with generators or for-comp, etc.)

Comment: Please, please, please measure. Please use `timeit` to measure this.  Please measure and post the results.

Comment: @S.Lott: He said nothing about performance.  The *preferred* way to do something does not imply the *fastest* way to do something.

Comment: If the question doesn't prefer performance, what does it prefer?  Memory use? If it's just style, the question is merely subjective and therefore, poor.   "Preferred" could mean anything.  Measurement is easy and can be done first.  If it's not measurable, then it's subjective.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your second example a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) would be better than list-comp if your list is large.

```
sum(1 for word in words if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1])
```

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()

Answer (score 3):

The first one would definitely be the preferred solution in Python.

Don't forget your Zen of Python:

> *The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters*
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>
> Explicit is better than implicit.
>
> Simple is better than complex.
>
> Complex is better than complicated.
>
> Flat is better than nested.
>
> Sparse is better than dense.
>
> **Readability counts.**
>
> Special cases aren't special enough to
>   break the rules.
>
> Although practicality beats purity.
>
> Errors should never pass silently.
>
> Unless explicitly silenced.
>
> In the face of ambiguity, refuse the
>   temptation to guess.
>
> There should be one-- and preferably
>   only one --obvious way to do it.
>
> Although that way may not be obvious
>   at first unless you're Dutch.
>
> Now is better than never.
>
> Although never is often better than
>   *right* now.
>
> If the implementation is hard to
>   explain, it's a bad idea.
>
> If the implementation is easy to
>   explain, it may be a good idea.
>
> Namespaces are one honking great idea
>   -- let's do more of those!

Other than that your solutions are good.

Comment: The usual formula of zen-of-Python-parroting: make a claim, and point at a line out of it as justification, as if it's some religious text.  (I find the second version very clear; the first looks like something ported from C.)

Comment: I completely disagree. List comprehensions are *very* Pythonic and readable.

Answer (score 2):

I personally find the explicit loop more readable, but it's much a matter of taste (some prefer shorter code generally, especially when they have to write it).

Either version can be further shortened/improved:

```
result = 0
for word in words:
    result += int(len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1])
return result
```

The int() conversions is strictly speaking unnecessary, since True is a kind of 1, but it may be better for readability. The same approach can apply to the comprehension:

```
return sum(len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1] for word in words)
```

If you want to use len(), I'd point the reader to the fact that the values don't really matter:

```
len(1 for word in words if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1])
```

Comment: `a += int(bool)` is unidiomatic to the point where I'd call it evil.  Don't do that; the original condition is much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are pretty good.

There are small differences:

List comprehension returns another list which you are passing to *len*. The first solution avoids creation of another list.

Answer (score 1):

Some other variants you might want to consider:

First, you can break the filter condition into a function.  This condition is fine either way, but if it becomes any more complex I'd definitely do this:

```
def check(word):
    return len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]
sum(1 for word in words if check(word))
```

Next, if generating a list (as in the original list comprehension) is acceptable, then you can do this:

```
len(filter(check, words))
```

There's itertools.ifilter, but if you use that you need to use the `sum` expression again, so it doesn't end up any clearer.

The `sum` trick comes up so often that I'm surprised there isn't a standard library call to count the number of items in an iterator (if there is, I havn't found it).  Alternatively, it'd make sense if `len` would consume and count the number of entries in an iterator if it has no `__len__`, but it doesn't.