# Python - Sum not working in list comprehension syntax if the source is file

Tags: python, sum, list-comprehension

I'm a newbie in Python and I'm studying list comprehension.

What I'm trying to do is to convert the following code into list comprehension:

```
def words_without_e():
    count = 0

    words = open('words.txt')
    for word in words:
        if word.find('e') == -1:
            count += 1
    words.close()

    return count
```

Here's my feeble attempt:

```
words = open('words.txt')
print sum([1 for word in words if word.find('e') == -1])
```

But unfortunately it's not working. The answer I expect to get is 37641, but I'm getting 0. :(

I tried creating another code doing the same thing but instead of file as source, I used a list:

```
def test():
    words = ['hello', 'world', 'ciao']
    return sum([1 for word in words if word.find('e') == -1])
```

And it works.

I saw this "quite" similar SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083098/list-comprehension-and-len-vs-simple-for-loop) and tried the code posted there `return len([word for word in words if len(word) >= 2 and word[0] == word[-1]])`. It works if the source is a hard-coded list but fails if the source is an external file.

Now, my question is, **does `sum` only works with lists and tuples?** If I understood the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) correctly, any iterable could be summed up.

Any enlightenment would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: How is your file formatted, is there one word per line? Your attempt seems to work for me...

Comment: @jamylak Yes, it's formatted that way.

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what happens? What does it print?

Comment: @mikej Just 0, which is obviously the wrong answer.

Comment: Try just `print(open('words.txt').readlines())` to check if there is any odd formatting in the file. It should look something like `['one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest solution is this:

```
with open("words.txt") as words:
  sum(1 for word in words if "e" not in word)
```

As you can see, `sum` does work with any iterator - here I am using a generator expression.

Rather than doing `word.find('e') == -1` we can just do `"e" not in word` which is nicer to read and works as strings are iterable themselves and support `__contains__`.

I am also using the `with` statement to open files - this is preferable to manually opening and closing them as it handles those things for you, and handles exceptions correctly too.

I would like to note however, your example works for me. My guess is that your file is space or comma delimited, but looping through a file returns lines.

My test file:

```
bob
bill
james
test
something
no
```

This, for example, will not work:

```
bob bill james test something no
```

As we will get one string containing the whole thing. In this case, we can use `str.split()` to split the lines into words.

E.g:

```
with open("words.txt") as lines:
    sum(1 for line in lines for word in line.split() if "e" not in word)
```

Comment: Works for `sum(1 for word in words if "e" not in word)` too.

Comment: @eumiro I let an extra pair of brackets slip in there.

Comment: I agree, your code is more readable than mine. :) Do you think the problem lies in word.find('e') == -1 not in the file per se as I first guessed?

Comment: @AnneLagang Nope, I tried your exact code and it worked for me. My suggestion is do ``for x in file: print(x)`` and see what output you get, might shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: @Lattyware I tried what you said but I didn't see anything weird on the formatting of the file. I uploaded the file so you can peruse it. http://www.box.com/s/d81312b5d6ac2176b039 Btw, thanks for the tip regarding `with`. I keep on closing files after I open them.

Comment: your last one won't work properly, should be `sum(1 for line in lines for word in line.split() if "e" not in word)`

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried this, and that works, so it could have something to do with how your file is formatted:

```
me@pc:~/Desktop$ cat > words.txt
app
noot
mies
wim
zus
jet
me@ps:~/Desktop$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> sum(1 for word in open('words.txt') if 'e' not in word)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I tried the code that @Lattyware wrote and it's working fine. I think I already found the culprit, although I don't understand why it behaves that way. I guess that will be for another question. :)

```
def count_words():
    with open("words.txt") as words:
        print sum(1 for word in words)
        print sum(1 for word in words if "e" not in word)


>>> count_words()
113809
0
```

But when I commented out the first print statement, it shows the answer correctly.

```
>>> count_words()
37641
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I'm posting the solution I came up with just in case somebody else encounters the same problem.

```
def count_words():
    total = 0
    wordsWithoutE = 0

    with open("words.txt") as words:
        for word in words:
            if 'e' not in word:
                wordsWithoutE += 1

            total += 1

    return (total, wordsWithoutE)


    >>> print count_words()
    (113809, 37641)
```

Comment: This is because the file is a stream; once you've iterated over it once (via the first `sum`), you're now at the end of the stream, and attempting to iterate over it again will not read any more data.

Comment: The solution here is to do ``stored = list(words)`` and then work from there. The list can be iterated over time and time again.