# Why is this listiterator stuck?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm thoroughly puzzled. I have a block of HTML that I scraped out of a larger table. It looks about like this:

```
<td align="left" class="page">Number:\xc2\xa0<a class="topmenu" href="http://www.example.com/whatever.asp?search=724461">724461</a> Date:\xc2\xa01/1/1999 Amount:\xc2\xa0$2.50 <br/>Person:<br/><a class="topmenu" href="http://www.example.com/whatever.asp?search=LAST&amp;searchfn=FIRST">LAST,\xc2\xa0FIRST </a> </td>
```

(Actually, it looked worse, but I regexed out a lot of line breaks)

I need to get the lines out, and break up the Date/Amount line. It seemed like the place to start was to find the children of that block of HTML. The block is a string because that's how regex gave it back to me. So I did:

```
text_soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
text_children = text_soup.find('td').childGenerator()
```

I can iterate through the children with

```
for i,each in enumerate(text_soup.find('td').childGenerator()):
    print type(each)
    print i, ":", each
```

but not with

```
for i, each in enumerate(text_children):
    ...etc
```

These ought to be the same. So I'm confused.

Comment: you mean `for i, each in enumerate(text_children):`?

Comment: They should work the same. Remember you can only iterate over text_children once as it will consume the generator.

Comment: @gnibbler, thanks for pointing out that I skipped the "enumerate" -- that I was doing fine in the console. I'm going to clarify my question, but ... what do you mean I can only iterate over text_children once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnibbler is correct in explaining that you could only consume generators once. Just to expound further:

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) an `iterator` is an object representing a stream of data. Since you already consumed the stream (i.e you reach the end of the stream), reiterating over it will not yield any data. I had the same problem before but Karl Knechtel's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103107/python-sum-not-working-in-list-comprehension-syntax-if-the-source-is-file/10103584#10103584) cleared things up for me. Hope my explanation is clear.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup's [`childGenerator()`](http://networkdynamics.org/static/zen/autogen/zen.util.BeautifulSoup-pysrc.html#Tag.childGenerator) method returns an [`iterator`](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) object via python's built in `iter()` function. An iterator has a `.next()` method which returns the next item or raises `StopIteration` when it runs out of elements.

An [enumerator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is a special kind of iterator.  It also has a `.next()` method, but instead of returning just the next value, it returns a tuple containing a count and the next value.

Your for loop takes two arguments (`i` and `each`) and so the python interpreter expects the iterator to supply a two-element tuple.  If you only pass in the iterator supplied by `childGenerator()`, python only has one element available instead of the two that it needs and chokes.  However, if you create an enumerator from the iterator via `enumerate()`, then the interpreter gets the two-element tuple it requires.

Comment: Eesh. Sorry, that was a typo. The issue wasn't enumerate. I need to add a lot to the question.

Comment: @gnibbler seems to have nailed it, though I still don't understand *why*. I'd already iterated through text_children once so iterating through it again was turning up nothing.